# Kotlin Native cinterop def file: how to eliminate absolute path?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

When specify linkerOpts, we need set absolute path for `-L` option, but it's easy to break.

In older version, setting `linkerOpts` in build.gradle could work, but in 1.3.50, it warns that "-linker-option(s)/-linkerOpts/-lopt option is not supported by cinterop. Please add linker options to .def file or binary compilation instead.", and build do fail with "Undefined symbols" error.

What could I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This option is going to be deprecated once, so the warning was intentionally added after the `1.3.50` release. The motivation here is that one should prefer to set all linker options, even [platform-specific](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/blob/master/INTEROP.md#c-compiler-and-linker-options), via `.def` file.
But, the build should not break apart in this case. Can you add the script contents, to make it clearer - what exactly led to the error?

---

UPD: After the GH project was shared in the comments I want to add some details here. This problem is described in the documentation [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#cinterop-support), this part:

> Often it's necessary to specify target-specific linker options for a binary which uses a native library. It can be done using the linkerOpts property of the binary.

So, in this particular case, it will be correct to add the option to the `binaries` section instead of the `cinterops`. In the end, I made things together with

```
binaries {
    all {
        linkerOpts = ['-L'+rootProject.projectDir+'/libs/NativeBase64/iOS/', '-lNativeBase64']
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I upload my project to GitHub: https://github.com/Piasy/KmppUtility , after clone (no need for submodule), running `./gradlew iosTest` at the project root directory (will need iOS development env, and iPhone 8 simulator), the last commit would fail with `Undefined symbols`, the next to last commit should work if you modify `KmppBase64/src/iosMain/cinterop/NativeBase64.def`'s content.

Comment: Hey @Piasy! It seems like I found the problem - look at the update above. If something will go wrong and it won't help, please ping me again.