# Kotlin/Native Windows cinterop using built library dll

Tags: c, gradle, kotlin, dll, kotlin-native

I am using Windows to follow the Kotlin-Native libcurl example here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/curl.html

Unfortunately, this has been a bigger challenge then I could have imagined. I have been learning how to compile C binaries on windows from source using tools such as CMake and have followed this tutorial to build libcurl on Windows: https://jonnyzzz.com/blog/2018/10/29/kn-libcurl-windows/

After quite a few days of trial and error with the .def file for cinterop on Windows, and using compilerOpts to point to my header file for curl in my built library, I have hit a brick wall.

I can't seem to get Gradle to recognize the dll file. Task ':linkDebugExecutableMingw' keeps failing. I have no idea where I am supposed to put the dll file. I have tried putting it in to the build output folder next to the exe, but it still fails to compile, with this error:

```
C:\Users\yous\.konan\dependencies\msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-clang-llvm-lld-compiler_rt-8.0.1\bin\ld: C:\Users\yous\AppData\Local\Temp\konan_temp6326583690522756621\result.o:out:(.rdata$.refptr.knifunptr_sample35_curl_easy_strerror[.refptr.knifunptr_sample35_curl_easy_strerror]+0x0): undefined reference to `knifunptr_sample35_curl_easy_strerror'
```

And a similar list of header file errors, then the final message is:

```
e: C:\Users\yabde\.konan\dependencies\msys2-mingw-w64-x86_64-clang-llvm-lld-compiler_rt-8.0.1/bin/clang++ invocation reported errors
```

This is after I succesfully located the header files. I believe this is an issue with the dll file not being included.

Here is my relevant Gradle build script:

```
mingwX64("mingw") {
        compilations.main {
            cinterops {
                libcurl {
                    // Def-file describing the native API.
                    // The default path is src/nativeInterop/cinterop/<interop-name>.def
                    defFile project.file("src/nativeInterop/cinterop/libcurl.def")

                    // Package to place the Kotlin API generated.
                    packageName 'libcurl'

                    // Options to be passed to compiler by cinterop tool.
                    compilerOpts '-Isrc\\nativeInterop\\cinterop\\libcurl-vc-x64-release-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl\\include -o libcurl'
                    //linkerOpts '-Isrc\\nativeInterop\\cinterop\\libcurl-vc-x64-release-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl\\bin'

                    // Directories for header search (an analogue of the -I<path> compiler option).
                    //includeDirs.allHeaders("path1", "path2")

                    // Additional directories to search headers listed in the 'headerFilter' def-file option.
                    // -headerFilterAdditionalSearchPrefix command line option analogue.
                    includeDirs.headerFilterOnly("src/nativeInterop/cinterop/libcurl-vc-x86-release-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl/include")

                    // A shortcut for includeDirs.allHeaders.
                    //includeDirs("include/directory", "another/directory")
                }
            }
        }
        binaries {
            executable {
                // Change to specify fully qualified name of your application's entry point:
                entryPoint = 'sample.main'
                // Specify command-line arguments, if necessary:
                //runTask?.args('-Lsrc/nativeInterop/cinterop/libcurl-vc-x86-release-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl/bin')
                runTask?.args('')
            }
        }
    }
```

I believe this issue may be with linker options to locate the dll, but uncommenting the linkerOpts line does not help.

I think I have given up on Kotlin/Native and will be sticking to C for data-oriented native programming...

**EDIT:**
**Also, note that any text commented out is things that I have attempted**
Ok so, this is my def file:

```
headers = curl/curl.h
headerFilter = curl/*

compilerOpts.linux = -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu

linkerOpts.osx = -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib -lcurl
linkerOpts.linux = -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcurl
linkerOpts.mingw = -Llibcurl-vc-x86-release-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl/lib
```

Ok so, this is my project structure:

[image: structure]

Comment: Hello! First of all, I would recommend you to have a look at [the sample](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/tree/master/samples/libcurl) from the official GH. In your exact case, I think the problem is that you use `-I` flag in the linker options.

Comment: Also, the linker options property of the `cinterops{}` block was deprecated. Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58919144/kotlin-native-cinterop-def-file-how-to-eliminate-absolute-path) question. In two words - one should prefer to use `.def` file to set the C interop settings.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev oh yes, I read about this and attempted to put my linkerOpts.mingW to -Lsrc/nativeInterop/cinterop/libcurl-vc-x86-release-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl/bin' to no avail.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev also, I've attempted linkerOpts.mingw = -lcurl like the sample, however, even after downloading it as well using pacman, it just says if can't find lcurl :(

Comment: Have you tried to use absolute paths? Also, can you please clarify the current state of your story - you managed to install MinGW, installed `curl`, and in the end, even the same sample project from the repository ain't working at all?  Also, maybe this hint would help - you can clone the K/N repository, change `/samples/gradle.properties:11` path to the downloaded compiler one, and try to work with it.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev Ok, so here's my story: I built libcurl windows dll, cloned Kotlin/Native, built the klib with cinterop cmd from gradle /.dist build of K/N, and I've been figuring out how to use it in my project from there. So, first I located include file with cinterops{} block, as I don't know how to do include location in def file, but now I'm stuck. Trying to figure out how to make linker options locate that actual library.  :(   I've updated my question with more details.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev I really appreciate the help by the way, this is a pretty obscure topic

Comment: Please try to use `linkerOpts.mingw= <absolute_path_to_libcurl.lib> -lcurl`.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev Alright, fantastic, it found the library, but now the issue is that mingw is skipping over the .lib when looking for lcurl, which I believe is due to it being 32 bit. This was fine for the C version, why in K/N does it need 64 bit? I tried using -m32 but then it assumes all of mingw is 32 bit and can't find any other libraries.

Comment: Are you putting this flag just into the linker options? Also, please try to use `-llibcurl` flag instead of the `-lcurl`.

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev Yes, I put this flag in the linkerOpts.mingw in the def file. And I just tried -libcurl which resulted in a "cannot find -libcurl" error. With -lcurl I get a "skipping incompatible ... libcurl.lib when searching for -lcurl".  These are my linker options ```linkerOpts.mingw = -LC:/Users/yousef/Desktop/Pet-Code/Web-Tests/http-client/src/nativeInterop/cinterop/libcurl-vc-x86-release-dll-ipv6-sspi-winssl/lib -lcurl```

Comment: Oh, maybe you should just try to target `minGWX86` to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the same steps (jonyzzz blog). I created a Libcurl static example for Kotlin-Native. Support for gzip and SSL. Compile to standalone exe, no need for dll

https://github.com/carlosrafp/Libcurl-Kotlin-Native-standalone

I built the static libraries supplied on the repository with mingw64 (gzip and libcurl) and msys2/mingw (openssl)

Answer (score 1):

I went through this question several times when looking for a solution for statically linking libcurl with my binary.

In the end, I ended up using WinInet for the HTTP communication on Windows. Linux and macOS binary still rely on ktor clients with libcurl.

See my example of how to use WinInet API with Kotlin MPP: https://github.com/localazy/kotlin-mpp-wininet

For a simple HTTP communication, WinInet API is good enough and the resulting binary is much smaller and in my case, it has no additional dependencies.

Comment: Dude, I'm so happy that my efforts were of benefit to you, this topic is ridiculously obscure so I imagined my question was a waste of space. I never ended up finding a solution, so I eventually gave up and learned C using CMake, that worked for a while, until it didn't, so I gave up and eventually used Visual Studio, and now my life is at peace. If you're trying to get anything done, I'd say move onto something common before becoming attached then suffering heartbreak like I did :(  Trust me man, there's plenty of fish in the ocean, Kotlin Native just isn't ready for a serious relationship.

Comment: I must disagree with you :-). We actually used Kotlin MPP to build our CLI app and since the most of the code was in the common module, it was great decision. Check this: https://localazy.com/blog/localazy-cli-sofware-localization-tool-kotlin-github